# В JavaScript содержимое переменных не копируется, а делается ссылка?

Tags: javascript

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в JS содержимое переменных не копируется, а делается ссылка?

Например такой код:

```
var testjson = {'Zero' :'0','One':'1','Two':'2'};
var test_var = testjson;
console.log(test_var);
test_var.Zero = '000'
console.log(test_var);
console.log(testjson);
```

Он вернёт:

```
{ Zero: '0', One: '1', Two: '2' }
{ Zero: '000', One: '1', Two: '2' }
{ Zero: '000', One: '1', Two: '2' }
```

Можно ли просто скопировать переменную не трогая её саму, как я понимаю это нужно делать через new?

```
Function testjson(){
var myvar = 'Zero' :'0','One':'1','Two':'2'
return myvar;
}

var test_var = new testjson();
```

Есть ли варианты попроще???

Comment: Целая подборка различных методов - [What is the most efficient way to clone an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object).

Comment: Если вы используете jQuery, то у него есть функция [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) для копирования объекта (NB: обратите внимание на аргумент `deep`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Читаем, вникаем, понимаем](http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/1658-peremennye-i-ssylki-na-peremennye.html) - по ссылке передаются только объекты, примитивные типы копируются.

> В JS нет ссылок на переменную.
>   Все переменные передаются по значению.
>   Только для переменной объектного типа значением является ссылка на структуру объекта.

Клонирование:

```js
function clone(o) {
 if(!o || ‘object’ !== typeof o)  {
   return o;
 }
 varc = ‘function’ === typeof o.pop ? [] : {};
 var p, v;
 for(p in o) {
 if(o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
  v = o[p];
  if(v && ‘object’ === typeof v) {
    c[p] = clone(v);
  }
  else {
    c[p] = v;
  }
 }
}
 return c;
}

var o = { a:1, get:function(){ alert(this.arr[1]);}, arr: [1,2,3] };
var c = clone(o); // делаем клон объекта
c.arr[0] = 77;
c.arr[1] = 88;
c.arr[2] = 99;

// Значения остались прежними
alert(o.arr[0]); // 1
alert(o.arr[1]); // 2
alert(o.arr[2]); // 3

// Методы тоже были скопированы
c.get(); // 88
o.get(); // 2
```

[Пруф.](http://snowcore.net/clone-javascript-object)

```js
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
 var f = function () {};
 f.prototype = this;
 var g = new f();
 g.prototype = this;
 return g;
}

var man = { name: "asdf", age: 21, sayHello: function () { alert("Hello, World!!!"); } };

var me = man.clone();

alert(me.name + " is " + me.age + " year old!");

me.sayHello();
```

[Пруф.](http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/2271-klonirovanie.html#post9011)

Comment: Вобщем понятно что "просто" это не происходит, не думал что простое копирование переменной может быть таким непростым :)

Comment: @vnn198, Оно как бы простое, разве что с объектами особенное.

Comment: ну учитывая что в JS все переменные "на одно лицо" то это вводит в заблуждение , логичнее когда одно действие всегда выдаёт один и тот-же результат

Comment: @vnn198, Да, неоднозначно, конечно, но исключения делают нашу жизнь приятнее, не находишь?

Comment: ну как сказать, это похоже как если сел в машину соседа , а там все педали местами поменяны, коробка переключается задом на перёд и руль в режиме инверсии, всё таки "ожидаемость поведения" упрощает жизнь :)

Comment: @vnn198, Кажется мне что это скорее философия, чем практика. Я люблю вникать в сложности, а кто-то хочет просто сделать и делает как можно проще.

Comment: ну скажу честно, технологии призванны упрощать жизнь, иначе это гумно а не технология, например навешись асинхронного г-на с node.js я понял что я хочу видеть и как хочу писать код, может как более-мене поднатаскаюсь в кодинге сделаю это либо библиотекой либо на крайняк форком ноды

Comment: @vnn198, Упрощать - это для юзеров. Программисты только за хардкор! xD